# In Emacs, how can I set the cursor-type globally?

Tags: emacs, cursor, text-cursor

It's possible to modify the style of the cursor by setting the value of the window local variable cursor-type.

```
(setq cursor-type '(hbar . 1))
```

How can I make all existing and future windows use the same cursor-type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setq-default` sets the default value of a variable:

```
(setq-default cursor-type '(hbar . 1))
```